# Loading Template in Admin Form for Custom Fields

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-admin

I learned that I can add a custom button in my Admin form by adding it to

```
    fields = ["connect"]
    readonly_fields = ('connect',)
    
    def connect(self, obj):
      return format_html("<button></button>")

    connect.allow_tags=True
    connect.short_description = ''
```

However, the html I want to add to the `connect` is getting out of control. I was wondering if there's a proper (Django-nic) way to move that to a template and load and return the content of the template in the `connect` function.

I can think of reading the content of the template file (`open('file.html', 'r')`) to read the content, however, I am looking for a suggestion that aligns Django standards (if any).

P.S. I also tried creating a view for getting the HTML content of the connect file, but that for some reason doesn't seem to work and feels unnatural to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
...
def connect(self, obj):
    html = render_to_string('file.html')
    return html
```

With `file.html` in `templates` directory